# SqlServer 2008 - deleting rows containing terms found in a black list table

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search, left-join, contains

I have two tables, one is a list of strings and the other contains a list of black listed words. I wish to find all the rows in the first table that their string contains a word from the second.

using like statement I created the following script and it worked:

`select a.string

from A a

left join BlackList b on a.string like '%' + b.Term + '%'

where b.Term is null`

I wanted to use full text search to get better performance. I was looking for a way to do this:

`select a.string

from A a

left join BlackList b on contains(a.string, b.Term)

where b.Term is null`

My research on the web discovered this is not possible, is their another way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run row by row so try CROSS APPLY. No match = no row from the CROSS APPLY query which is the same as LEFT JOIN..IS NULL

```
select
   a.string
from
   A a
   CROSS APPLY
   (SELECT b.Term FROM BlackList b WHERE contains(a.string, b.Term)) foo
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We came to the same concluson, but since our black list is significantly smaller the fts has no advantage.